# ClassNotFoundException org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic

Tags: maven, jboss, hornetq, wildfly-9, jms-topic

I'm trying to use http-remoting from a Java client with a remote wildfly 9. This always results in the ClassNotFoundException.

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>iz.alerting</groupId>
    <artifactId>AlertingClientTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.2.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
            <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
            <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is a very simple Java Main class that illustrates the problem.

```java
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not find org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic",e1);
        }

        Properties env= new Properties();
        String url="http-remoting://servername:12080";
        log.log(Level.INFO,"Connecting to server "+url);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "xxx");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxx");
        InitialContext remoteContext=null;
        try {
            remoteContext = new InitialContext(env);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not create initialcontext", e);
        }
        Topic topic=null;
        String eventname = "jms/izalerting/alertresult";
        if(remoteContext!=null){
            try {
                topic = (Topic) remoteContext.lookup(eventname);
                if(topic == null) {
                    log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not find topic" + eventname+ ". It was null");
                }
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not find topic" + eventname, e);
            }finally {
                try {
                    remoteContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not close remoteContext", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Wildfly standalone.xml I have this definition regarding the JMS topic called `jms/izalerting/alertresult`.

```xml
<jms-destinations>
    <jms-topic name="izalertAlertresult">
        <entry name="jms/izalerting/alertresult"/>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/izalerting/alertresult"/>
    </jms-topic>
</jms-destinations>
```

This program always results in a ClassNotFoundException  on the line `topic = (Topic) remoteContext.lookup(eventname);`. Below I've added the full output of the program.

I've added the `Class.forName("org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic");`in the beginning of the program because I don't understand why it isn't found. It should be made available by the maven dependency `hornetq-jms-client`.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue? Do I need an additional maven dependency?

I'm fairly sure that the connection to the server succeeds because when I remove the principal and credentials lines it says that it can not authenticate.

```
mrt 20, 2019 1:32:24 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Could not find org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)

mrt 20, 2019 1:32:24 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: Connecting to server http-remoting://servername:12080
mrt 20, 2019 1:32:24 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
mrt 20, 2019 1:32:25 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
mrt 20, 2019 1:32:25 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
mrt 20, 2019 1:32:26 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Could not find topicjms/izalerting/alertresult
org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:276)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at Main.main(Main.java:43)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:159)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.BaseProtocolCommand.readResult(BaseProtocolCommand.java:59)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleClientMessage(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver$1.run(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:948)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1255)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:156)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Just a guess: Does it work, if you remove the `runtime` scope from your `<artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>`?

Comment: @mle, no it doesn't. At compile time (default scope = compile, I think) I don't use anything specific from hornetq-jms-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The `ClassNotFoundException` was actually caused by a `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`. Apparently a bad jar was downloaded from the maven repositories.

The issue was resolved by deleting the .m2 directory an redownloading the maven dependencies.